# Using DateTime instead of Date in Google chart CandlestickChart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to use datetime instead of date to build chart using the Google-chart API.

Based on the sample from Google ([sample](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls_375962c65645056cc8a1b843d259f20c.frame))

```
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Stock low');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Stock open');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Stock close');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Stock high');

 data.addRows([
                  [new Date(2008, 1 ,1), 1000, 1000, 1500, 2000],
                  [new Date(2008, 1 ,2), 500, 1000, 1500, 2500],
                  [new Date(2008, 1 ,3), 1000, 1000, 1500, 2000]
    ]);
```

I can play with dates, but I want to use date & hours, something like

```
data.addRows([
              [new Date(2008, 1 ,1, 00, 00, 00), 1000, 1000, 1500, 2000],
              [new Date(2008, 1 ,1, 01, 00, 00), 500, 1000, 1500, 2500],
              [new Date(2008, 1 ,1, 02, 00, 00), 1000, 1000, 1500, 2000]

]);
```

This give me the [following output](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/632918chartError.jpg)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

To clarify Mark's answer, change your line

```
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
```

to

```
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
```

this seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You want 'datetime', not 'date'.